# *quant'altro* Vs. *quant'altre*

Tags: grammar

> Un 'mercato' come quello UE, dove s'impongono quote latte, quote olio, quote arance e *quant'altre*, è come l'URSS dei piani quinquennali.

È corretto nella sopra trascritta frase usare *quant'altre*, essendo, o intendendosi, *altre* riferita a *quote*?

O si deve necessariamente scrivere *quant'altro*?

Comment: Onestamente in questa frase non userei né *quant'altro* né *quant'altre* ma piuttosto *e via dicendo* o *eccetera*.

Comment: L'uso di “e quant'altro” è un modismo mutilo (una troncatura di un'espressione come “e quant'altro si voglia considerare” o simili).

Answer (score 5):

Non è corretto utilizzare al femminile 'quant'altro' in quanto è un’espressione usata per dire:

e così via

eccetera

Quindi non va declinata al femminile e non si riferisce ad una parola della frase in particolare.

È un'espressione probabilmente presa dal linguaggio giuridico/burocratico che ultimamente è molto in auge nella lingua parlata ma comunque il suo uso è sconsigliato.

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/uso-abuso-quantaltro